# How to connect two windows 8.1 laptop with Lan cable to play multi-player games?

Tags: windows-8, ethernet, game-controller, lenovo-desktop-computer

Connecting laptop for playing multiigames by lan cable on windows 7 is easy. But I don't know how to connect it on windows 8.1.
Can you please help me by giving me step by step by instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Try it the same way. 
Basically there is no difference in connecting two PCs with Windows 7 or Windows 8 or Windows 10. 
One could even think of connecting a Windows 7 machine with a Windows 10 machine and again do it the same way...

To get more into detail:

If you have DHCP in your network (your computer automatically gets an IP address once it is powered on) and some LAN cables, just connect your computers to the same network the DHCP is in. 
If you like to use a Peer-To-Peer-Connection, set a (for each different) static IP address on both your computers and connect them directly with a LAN cable.

For more details on how to achive this, you could follow this link:

[How to Connect Two Computers Together with an Ethernet Cable](http://www.wikihow.com/Connect-Two-Computers-Together-with-an-Ethernet-Cable)